# Module and Parameter with the same name

Tags: python

I have seen a question on SO about having a Parameter and a Function with the same name, and how to deal with that, but I haven't found one that deals with having a parameter and a module with the same name.

I would prefer to avoid using the `from x import *` importing method in favor of `import x`.  However, this leads me to the situation where I have a parameter to a function named `x`, which is the same as the module name `x`.  What are the cleanest ways to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the imported module to something else, so it lives in a different namespace:

```
import x as y
```

then you can use the imported object with a differently chosen name.

Comment: Doh! That's very clever and simple.  That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much!!  (I will accept as soon as I can.)